# Accessing UserName from the Web Service Implementation Class in Java

Tags: java, web-services

After authenticating a user using CXF WSAuthentication Interceptor... I need the username in the service implementation (Business Logic).  Wondering if there is a easy way to get access to the Username in the Implementation class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare these in your implementation class:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

then in any method do:

```
Principal p = wsContext.getUserPrinciple();
String username = p.getName();
```

@Resource instructs the web service stack to inject the web service context into your wsContext attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a user object and place it somewhere in the memory (in a static Map or List etc) with the userName in the wsse:security while while doing the authentication itself? Once you reach the Service endpoint implementation class, you loose the MessageContext and hence its difficult to read the headers.